# Can't convert from DTO to POCO from one solution to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I'm having the strangest problem and I know it's because I'm missing something obvious because this set up works fine when I save data and even pull it down.

My app is set up like so ....

WebUI depends on Business Layer .. Business Layer depends on Data Layer (which is where I'm actually pulling the data).  The Business Layer does all the "work".

This is where everything dies (Null Exception, Object Reference not set) as soon as I assign something to userInfo.userData.avatarFilepath (which is not null).

```
namespace pgl.businesslayer
{
    public class userCtx
    {
    private pgl.datalayer.Concrete.EFDbContext context = new pgl.datalayer.Concrete.EFDbContext();
    private pgl.datalayer.Concrete.EFUserContext userContext = new pgl.datalayer.Concrete.EFUserContext();
    private pgl.datalayer.Concrete.EFDbCompany companyContext = new pgl.datalayer.Concrete.EFDbCompany();

    public ViewModels.UserInfo getUserById(int userId)
    {
        ViewModels.UserInfo userInfo = new ViewModels.UserInfo();

        pgl.datalayer.Dtos.pglUserDTO userDL = userContext.getUserByUserId(userId);

        userInfo.userData.avatarFilepath = userDL.avatarFilepath;
        userInfo.userData.createdBy = userDL.createdBy;
        userInfo.userData.createdDate = userDL.createdDate;
        userInfo.userData.email = userDL.email;
        userInfo.userData.firstName = userDL.firstName;
        userInfo.userData.lastName = userDL.lastName;
        etc...
    }
```

ViewModels.UserInfo looks like this...

```
namespace pgl.businesslayer.ViewModels
{
  public class UserInfo
    {
    // user info
    public pgl.businesslayer.Dto.pglUser userData { get; set; }
    // salon info
    public List<pglSalon> salonsData { get; set; }
    // company info
    public pglCompany companyData { get; set; }        
}
```

pglUser in the business layer looks like this and is just a POCO

```
namespace pgl.businesslayer.Dto
{
    public class pglUser
    {
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public byte[] passwordSalt { get; set; }
    public byte[] passwordKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public int createdBy { get; set; }
    public bool passwordResetRequired { get; set; }
    public string passwordHash { get; set; }
    public string tempPassword { get; set; }
    public string userType { get; set; }
    public string avatarFilepath { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

And in userContext this is how I am pulling the user data...

```
public pgl.datalayer.Dtos.pglUserDTO getUserByUserId(int userId)
    {
        var getUser = (from u in context.pglUser
                       select new pgl.datalayer.Dtos.pglUserDTO
                       {
                           username = u.username,
                           companyId = u.companyId,
                           userId = u.userId,
                           userType = u.userType,
                           firstName = u.firstName,
                           lastName = u.lastName,
                           email = u.email,
                           createdDate = u.createdDate,
                           createdBy = u.createdBy,
                           passwordResetRequired = u.passwordResetRequired,
                           tempPassword = u.tempPassword,
                           avatarFilepath = u.avatarFilepath,
                           timeZone = u.timeZone
                       }).Where(u => u.userId == userId).FirstOrDefault();



        return getUser;
    }
```

pgl.datalayer.Dtos.pglUserDTO looks like this...

```
namespace pgl.datalayer.Dtos
{
    public class pglUserDTO
    {
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public byte[] passwordSalt { get; set; }
    public byte[] passwordKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public int createdBy { get; set; }
    public bool passwordResetRequired { get; set; }
    public string passwordHash { get; set; }
    public string tempPassword { get; set; }
    public string userType { get; set; }
    public string avatarFilepath { get; set; }
    public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Even if I assign userInfo.userData.avatarFilepath = "WHATUP!!!" it throws the same error.  This has got to be something stupid and simple.  I can save data with no problem and when I debug I can see that it is actually pulling the correct user ID and it's associated data.  It's just that pgl.businesslayer.ViewModels.UserInfo seems to be un-instantiated.  I'm at a loss.  I can provide more info... and keep in mind I'm kind of at my wits end so I tried doing weird things like adding (probably) unnecessary DTOs.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be creating the userData object anywhere. When you create a new instance of UserInfo, or in its constructor, try adding:

```
userData = new pgl.businesslayer.Dto.pglUser();
```

Or alternatively:

```
    ViewModels.UserInfo userInfo = new ViewModels.UserInfo();

    pgl.datalayer.Dtos.pglUserDTO userDL = userContext.getUserByUserId(userId);

    userInfo.userData = new pgl.businesslayer.Dto.pglUser {
        avatarFilepath = userDL.avatarFilepath,
        createdBy = userDL.createdBy,
        createdDate = userDL.createdDate,
        email = userDL.email,
        firstName = userDL.firstName,
        lastName = userDL.lastName
   };
```

If you always want to initialise UserInfo with an empty userData member, you could include the creation within the constructor:

```
namespace pgl.businesslayer.ViewModels
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        // Default constructor
        public UserInfo()
        {
            userData = new pgl.businesslayer.Dto.pglUser();
        }

        // user info
        public pgl.businesslayer.Dto.pglUser userData { get; set; }
        // salon info
        public List<pglSalon> salonsData { get; set; }
        // company info
        public pglCompany companyData { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Comment: So in namespace pgl.businesslayer.ViewModels.UserInfo I should add that?

Comment: Ahh your edit makes sense.  I'll try that as soon as I get home.  Thanks dude.

Comment: Hope it helps. I've also added an example of creating an empty instance in the constructor, though I think the first example, using an object initializer, is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Just FYI - that did it.  Thanks Alan.